# How to get request url in a jQuery $.get/ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$.get('http://www.example.org', {a:1,b:2,c:3}, function(xml) {}, 'xml');
```

Is there a way to fetch the url used to make the request after the request has been made (in the callback or otherwise)?

I want the output:

```
http://www.example.org?a=1&b=2&c=3
```

Comment: When you call the get() method, you need to pass url and parameter. So why don't you build a string for complete url in callback function?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I can't get it to work on `$.get()` because it has no `complete` event.

I suggest to use `$.ajax()` like this,

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.example.org',
    data: {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},
    dataType: 'xml',
    complete : function(){
        alert(this.url)
    },
    success: function(xml){
    }
});
```

## [craz demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tu6Zr/)

Comment: So smart! I'm surprised this.url isn't available in the success callback

Comment: Is there any way to do the same in angularjs ?

Comment: I'm not sure.. I'm not familiar with angularjs... you should make a separate question about it...

Comment: @BennyNeugebauer the answer is not using corresponding `jqXHR.success()` or `jqXHR.complete()` methods. The ajax **callback options** `success` and `complete` are **not** deprecated.

Comment: @BennyNeugebauer is incorrect. The **jQuery** `success` and `complete` callbacks are not deprecated as of jQuery version 3.4.1.

Answer (score 4):

Since jQuery.get is just a shorthand for jQuery.ajax, another way would be to use the latter one's `context` option, as stated in the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> The `this` reference within all callbacks is the object in the context option passed to `$.ajax` in the settings; if context is not specified, this is a reference to the Ajax settings themselves.

So you would use

```
$.ajax('http://www.example.org', {
  dataType: 'xml',
  data: {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},
  context: {
    url: 'http://www.example.org'
  }
}).done(function(xml) {alert(this.url});
```

Comment: Thanks. I url helped debug my form submission error in Rails. A new resource was created with 'new' action path of MyResource controller http://localhost:3000/my_resource/new. A link made AJAX request to custom Rails controller action 'change_partial'. In AJAX options I used `type: 'GET', url: 'change_partial', dataType: 'html'`. Clicking link called backend controller action, returning rendered HTML partial. But submitting form with validation errors rendered 'create' path http://localhost:3000/my_resource/, & clicking link caused errors. Fixed by change `url: 'my_resource/change_partial'`