# How to change URL after an ajax request?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a menu with some links that update the div `content` and execute the function `onSuccess` after it is loaded.

```
<li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "home")</li>
<li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Download", "Index", "download")</li>
```

If I am on the url `/home` and click the download link the div changes successfully. The problem is that the URL is not changed.

How can I retrieve the requested URL so I can call `history.pushState` on successful requests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [this question (How to get request url in a jQuery $.get/ajax request)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3828104/340760) I found out that I can retrieve it with `this.url`.

From [MDC window.history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.history) I found the syntax and from [MDC Manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) I found that I can get the current state with `history.state` (doesn't seem to work on Chrome though) and discovered that when calling `pushState` I can only send 640k characters on the `stateObject` or else it throws an exception.

My current method for successful ajax requests is:

```
OnSuccess: function(html, status, xhr){
    var requestedUrl = this.url.replace(/[&?]X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest/i, "");

    // if the url is the same, replace the state
    if (window.location.href == requestedUrl)
    {
        history.replaceState({html:html}, document.title, requestedUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        history.pushState({html:html}, document.title, requestedUrl);
    }
},
```

For a basic test I am storing the entire result on the `stateObject`, if it throws an exception I will set the URL instead to be able to make a new request.

My `popstate` event is

```
$(window).bind("popstate", function (e) {
    var state = e.originalEvent.state;
    $("#body").html(state.html);
});
```

It restores the page as it was previously, I don't need to make a new request.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of achieving this is by using jQuery to handle the click event of the links. So you could add a class attribute to your links as follows;

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "home", new { @class = "menuLinks" })
```

The add your click event;

```
$(".menuLinks").click(function() {
   history.pushState(stateObj, $(this).html, $(this).attr("href"));
}
```

Not very familar with the pushState signature but I believe using the href of the 'a' tag will work as a valid url to pass to the pushState.