# Is it possible to pass variable in ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**Is it possible to pass variable in ajax call?**

```
$(document).on('click','#Quote_create_value',function(){ 
            $template = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'GET',
                    url : '../../../protected/config/ajax.php',     
                    data:"function=result($template)",
                    success : function(response){
                        $("#Quote_template_value").html(response);
                    }
                });
           });
```

**In ajax.php, I have that fuction.I want to call result function in the ajax.php**
**I am not getting the respose.**

```
if(isset($_GET['function'])) {
    if($_GET['function'] == 'templateDropDown') {
        $query = "select * from quote where template IS NOT NULL";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $con);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['template'].'">' . $row['template'] . '</option>';
        }
        mysql_free_result($result);
    } 
    elseif($_GET['function'] == 'result($template)') {
        $query = "select * from template where templateName=$template";
        $result = mysql_query($query,$con);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo $row['unitcost'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413969/pass-variable-to-function-in-jquery-ajax-success-callback

Comment: I'm assuming you want $template to be the var 'template'?

Comment: As it stands this question is quite unclear. Is `result` a PHP function?

Comment: So is `result` a JS function and you want to pass the value it returns to your AJAX call?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on('click','#Quote_create_value',function(){ 
            $template = $(this).val();
            var functionVal = result($template)
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'GET',
                    url : '../../../protected/config/ajax.php',
                    data:"function=result("+functionVal+")",
                    success : function(response){
                        $("#Quote_template_value").html(response);
                    }
                });
           });
```

Comment: I not getting the response. I think there is some error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes... you can do this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
      alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
```

});

Please check the documentation of jQuery for ajax requests: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to pass the value of `$template` to be used in a PHP function called `result`, you can do this:

```
// no advantage to using 
// $(document).on('click','#Quote_create_value'
$('#Quote_create_value').on('click', function() {  
    var $template = $(this).val();   // no longer a global variable        
    $.get({                          // shorthand for AJAX GET request
        url : '../../../protected/config/ajax.php',     
        data : { function : result($template) },
        success : function(response) {
            $("#Quote_template_value").html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

This passes the result of the JS function `result($template)` to `url`. For a `GET` request, jQuery will serialise the `data` attribute and form a query string which will be appended to the URL. If you wanted, you could just do this yourself by changing the `url` attribute to

```
url : '../../../protected/config/ajax.php&function=' + result($template)
```

and not specifying a `data` attribute.

Either way, `$_GET['function']` on the server will contain your data.