# Nested jQuery Ajax - Pass 1st ajax response global variable data into the 2nd ajax for processing

Tags: javascript, ajax

I know about the js async issues which is why I came up with the following 2 functions in order to put an ajax inside a reusable function call so I can use it in other parts of the site. The work perfectly fine when done with callbacks.

But the problem I have below is that I need a variable from **getBlocks()** ajax call that needs to be in the 2nd ajax call **getAcct()**. I have a for loop in the first ajax call that calls the 2nd ajax call on each iteration to get the name of the account. I've tried to set the global variable **qq**, but it always shows undefined.

How would one go about solving the below issue?

```
//get nxt blockchain transactions
function getBlocks(acct, ip, pikachu) {
     $.ajax({
         url: 'http://'+ ip +'/nxt?=%2Fnxt&requestType=getBlockchainTransactions&account=' + acct + '+&withMessage=true',
         dataType: 'json',
         success: pikachu
     }); //get account name
}

//get nxt account info
function getAcct(acct, ip, zelda) {
     $.ajax({
         url: 'http://'+ ip +'/nxt?=%2Fnxt&requestType=getAccount&account=' +  acct  + '+&withMessage=true',
         dataType: 'json',
         success: zelda
     }); //get account name
}


getBlocks(nxtacct, nxtip, function(response) {
      var xx = [];
      xx = response.transactions;

      for( i = 0; i < xx.length; i++)  {
        yy = xx[i].senderRS;
        var qq;

        getAcct(yy, nxtip, function(response) {
          qq = response.name;
        });

        jQuery(targetb).append("<tr>");
        jQuery(targetb).append("<td>" + xx[i].amountNQT +"</td>");
        jQuery(targetb).append("<td>" + xx[i].feeNQT + "</td>");
        jQuery(targetb).append('<td><a href="https://test.nxtportal.org/accounts/'+ xx[i].sender +'" target="_blank">' + qq + "<em>" + yy + "</em>"  + "</a></td>");
        jQuery(targetb).append("<td>" + xx[i].recipientRS + "</td>");
        jQuery(targetb).append("<td>" + xx[i].message+ "</td>");
        jQuery(targetb).append("<td>" + date +"</td>");
        jQuery(targetb).append("</tr>");
     } //for
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify and access custom AJAX properties using `this`. Simply specify the property inside the AJAX call, as shown here.

```
//get nxt account info
function getAcct(acct, ip, myCustomValue, zelda) {
    $.ajax({
         url: '...',
         dataType: 'json',
         myCustomProperty: myCustomValue,
         success: zelda
     }); //get account name
}
```

And then access your property inside the `zelda` function like this.

```
function zelda(response) {
    var valueFromGetAcct = this.myCustomProperty;

    // do stuff
}
```

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413969/pass-variable-to-function-in-jquery-ajax-success-callback) for more info.

Comment: my problem is getting the **qq** variable out of the ajax call. Or should I put all the appends inside 2nd ajax call?

Comment: no you are correct. this is how its done. The trick was to get all of the ajax calls into their own function call.