# How to get request url in an angularjs $http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, request

I have this request:

```
$http({
  method: 'get',
  url: '/api/items/',
  params: {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
}).success(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
}).error(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Is there a way, to fetch the url it used to make the request after the request has been made(in the callback or otherwise)?

I would want the output:

```
http://www.example.org/api/items?a=1&b=2&c=3
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828104/how-to-get-request-url-in-a-jquery-get-ajax-request) the same thing is done with jquery.

Comment: It's not working using `params` ?

Comment: $location.search('target') seems to not work even in promise success function.

Answer (score 2):

The success handler gets 4 parameters passed into it:

```
$http
  .get({ url: '/someUrl', params: { q: 3 } })
  .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {});
```

The fourth parameter `config` has the following properties:

```
{
  method: "GET",
  url: {
    url: '/someUrl',
    params: {
      q: 3
    }
  }
}
```

You can use `window.location.origin` to get the base url and build a simple function to concat it all together.

This function should yield the expected response:

```
var baseUrl = window.location.origin;
var query = [];
Object.keys(config.url.params || {}).forEach(function (key) {
  var val = config.url.params[key];
  query.push([key, val].join('=')); // maybe url encode
});
var queryStr = query.join('&');
var fullPath = baseUrl + config.url.url + '?' + queryStr;
```

Unfortunately, this function will only work as long as the parameters are passed in the format described above. If you pass them in a different format, you'll have to modify this function a bit. You can [use this as a playground](https://jsbin.com/toniqakiru/edit?html,output).

Afaik, there is no simpler way. At least a [feature request exists](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/738).

[See the docs of $http for reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage)

Comment: that `url` gives me only the path without the parameters

Comment: [Check this example](https://jsbin.com/toniqakiru/edit?html,output) - the url contains the query parameter as well.

Comment: the example is working because params are attached to the url (`/url?q=3`). But in my case, params are given separately (`params: {q:3}`)

Comment: is the function working for you? I get `config.url.params` as `undefined` and it is giving me this error `Cannot convert undefined or null to object` in forEach part. Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: The function above will only work as long as you pass the parameters in the described format. If you pass them in a slightly different format, you'll have to modify the function.

Answer (score 0):

This config parameter of the callback has the url as a property:

```
// Simple GET request example :
$http.get('/someUrl').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(config.url);
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Based on: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: that would give me only `/someUrl` without params

Answer (score 0):

You can use http request Interceptor.
Configure the Interceptor in config function using $httpProvider
Whrein for request Interceptor you can able to see the URL and params that you passed with URL prior to making the request

Comment: can you share the code here. how to get the URL and param inside $httpInterceptor

Answer (score 0):

try just looking at the XHR Request urls in your browser dev tools